# negate a specific word in regex

Tags: regex

I have following text to match through regex

> a href="https://www.bing.com/aclk"

But i don't want this type of links to match if bing is coming in domain.

I tried following regular expressions as answered in one of stackoverflow answers.but it matches.

```
a href="(https?://(?!bing)[^"]+)"
```

or

```
a href="(https?://(?:www\.)?(?!bing)[^"]+)"
```

I would like a regular expression which will return links that don't match links which contain the word `bing` in the domain.

Comment: Does your environment support URL api ? if yes use URL api to parse url and check does domain name contain `bing` or not

Comment: `www.anybingany.com` would be valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative look ahead to filter what is allowed in the domain.

```
a href="(https?://(?![^/"]*bing)[^"]+)"
```

Note that you might have to escape the slashes, depending how you are using this regex:

```
a href="(https?:\/\/(?![^\/"]*bing)[^"]+)"
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/25IIac/2)